# Angular Reactive Forms with MatSelect and MatCard

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-6

Ok so I am retrieving a list of games from a database and dynamically displaying them in the browser. I want tobe able to validate each game item using a quantity in a angular material select. However I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'orders -> quantity'

Any ideas what I am doing wrong??

```
 <mat-card *ngFor="let game of gamesDisplayed; let i=index">
    <mat-card-title>
        <h2 >{{game.Name}}</h2>
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div formArrayName="orders">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="quantity" required>
                    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="3">3</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="4">4</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="5">5</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="6">6</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="7">7</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="8">8</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="9">9</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
           <mat-form-field>
      </form
    </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    orders: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        quantity: [{value: '', disabled: false}, Validators.required]
      })
    ])
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
this.gameInventory$.subscribe((games: any) => {
  this.gamesDisplayed = games;
  (<FormArray>this.form.controls['orders']).removeAt(0); //<-- remove empty control
  this.gamesDisplayed.forEach((value) => {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['orders'];
    control.push(this.formBuilder.group
      ({
          quantity: [{value: '', disabled: false}, Validators.required]
      })
    )
  });
})
```

Comment: You have specified `formControlName` in the template, but you are creating a `formGroup` using `formBuilder`. Try creating control with `formBuilder` inside `formArray`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the HTML template and I fixed it like so:

```
<form [formGroup]="form"> 
    <mat-card formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let game of gamesDisplayed; let i=index">
    <mat-card-title>
        <h2 >{{game.Name}}</h2>
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="quantity" required>
                    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="3">3</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="4">4</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="5">5</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="6">6</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="7">7</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="8">8</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="9">9</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
           <mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>
</form>
```